# Can't insert links to DB

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have this code:

```
    if (!empty($_POST['w1']) && !empty($_POST['l1']))   {
        $str = "<a href='".$_POST['l1']."'>".$_POST['w1']."</a>";
        $content = str_replace($_POST['w1'],$str, $content);
    }
    $content = nl2br($content);
    echo "נוסף";
    echo $content;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` VALUES ('','".$_POST['subject']."','$content','0')");
```

The php page doesn't return any error. But the data isn't inserted to the DB.
Anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: I just think error reporting is off, the query looks wrong to me.

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` VALUES ('','".$_POST['subject']."','{$content}','0')");

Comment: Error reporing is on. And i check the query few times and didn't find anything wrong about it.

Comment: To display MySQL errors, use `mysql_error()` and `mysql_errno()`.

Comment: I added it. It didn't return any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is any mysql error thrown, it will not be shown to you. Do the following to see an error:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` VALUES ('','". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($content) . "','0')") or die mysql_error();
```

Be aware of SQL-Injections!

Comment: Thank you! once I added the `mysql_real_escape_strin()` it solved my prolem. I'm not really sure why. it didn't print an error. it just worked. do you know maybe why?

Comment: If you have chars like ' into your user input, they will smash your SQL-Statement since something like [userinput: foobar] "VALUES('foobar')" can become [userinput: foo'bar]  "VALUES('foo'bar')" which of cause leads to an syntax error.

Comment: Additional note: This behavior is at least annoying, but can be also be abused to do socalled SQL injections. It is a giant security risk, so you should maybe inform yourself about it: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 2):

You have put single quotes for $content in query which is not needed.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` VALUES ('','".$_POST['subject']."','$content','0')");
```

Change it to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` VALUES ('','".$_POST['subject']."','".$content."','0')");
```

Comment: Actually, it is not a good coding style to use variables in a string, but it is allowed, so that wouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

PHP parser doesn't return any error so the error is probably on the database side.
One thing out of top of my head is to replace

```
INSERT INTO `posts` VALUES ('','".$_POST['subject']."','$content','0')
```

with

```
INSERT INTO `posts` VALUES (NULL,'".$_POST['subject']."','$content','0')
```

bacause your db configuration might not allow construct you are trying to use.